# Overwrite/Remove previous character in LaTeX

Tags: jurabib

I'm looking for a command in LaTeX that overwrites or removes the previous characters which were automatically created by a package I use.

---

I'm using the [jurabib package](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/jurabib) for my citations. For example with this command:

```
\cite[Pages 3-5]{key}
```

It has an option to automatically create a comma before the page range (`commabeforerest`).
Which is what I need for most citations.
This would look like:

```
Author, Title, Pages 1-3.
```

There is one cite where I do not need the comma. 
So I want to know if there is a way to overwrite the previous two characters (the automatically created space and comma), so I could use something like this command for my special cite:

```
\cite[\OverwritePreviousChars{2} Pages 4-6]{key}
```

Which would create this:

```
Author, Title Pages 4-6.
```

Comment: not really possible once you have typeset the comma. You could try to overprint a white coloured box but really it would be better to parameter the macros not to add the comma.

Comment: as always it would be much easier for people to answer if you edited the question to provide a small test file that typesets a citation with an unwanted comma

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!  Please take a moment to take our [Tour](http://tex.stackexchange.com/tour)!  You may also want to look at what makes a good Minimal Working Example ([MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that))

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can reset the switch used by commebeforerest. But it is naturally much easier to simply type the Pages info after the \cite.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{jurabib}
\bibliographystyle{jurabib}
\jurabibsetup{ commabeforerest,}

\begin{document}
\cite[Pages 3-5]{doody}

{\makeatletter\jb@comma@before@restfalse\makeatother 
\cite[Pages 3-5]{doody}}

\cite{doody} Pages 3-5

\bibliography{biblatex-examples}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

I don't have the reputation to comment, so instead I post as an answer. In LuaTeX you can indeed remove the previous character that TeX has seen! Hans talked about it in this [article](https://www.tug.org/TUGboat/tb36-2/tb113hagen.pdf), funnily enough for the same purpose of handling bibliographical bits and bobs.